# <cfcontent type="text/json"> opens download dialog, and other ajax weirdness

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion

We recently set up a new website on our server: Windows 2K8 R2/IIS7/ColdFusion8 Ent. A key query which works no problem locally now doesn't work in production.

Using `<cfcontent type="text/json">` in the cfc function below causes the browser to open a download dialog box when a template calls this function.

```
<cffunction name="getPolls" access="remote" returntype="any" hint="Gets Polls">
    <cfargument name="poll_id" type="numeric" required="true">    
    <cfset var qPoll = 0>
        <cfquery name="qPoll" datasource="#application.datasource#">
            select * from polls where poll_id = #arguments.poll_id#
        </cfquery> 
        <cfcontent type="text/json">
        <cfreturn qPoll>
</cffunction>
```

Below is the jQuery code which calls the above function. When this code is run inside a template (test.cfm), the download dialog opens asking me to save the file test.cfm rather than actually browsing the template.

```
$(function(){       
    var poll_id = global_poll_id || 0;
    var uniqueid = new Date().getTime();
    $.getJSON("/cfcs/poll.cfc?method=getPolls&returnformat=json&queryformat=column&uniqueid=" + uniqueid, {"poll_id":poll_id}, function(res,code) {     
        alert(res.ROWCOUNT); // error here
    })
})
```

If I remove the `<cfcontent type="text/json">` from the function, the download dialog no longer appears; HOWEVER, the ajax callback doesn't seem to fire and an error returns:

```
res is not defined
```

Comment: you url/params is a bit weird, but nothing wrong. Are you certain you don't load jquery 2 times? Did you try to use just .get() instead of .getJSON()?. Anyway, You should handle the .error function, at least for debug purpose, and "console.log" your code prm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was related to my application.cfc. I needed to completely remove the onRequest method to get it working.

Answer (score 3):

The correct mime type for json is application/json so adding text/json could be causing the download prompt as this mime possibly isn't mapped in IIS.

You don't strictly need to add the `cfcontent`, manipulating the headers may be a better approach. Either way jQuery will parse it to json. Inspect the response and headers in your web inspector and you may find out more regarding the issue.

Comment: There's something wrong in the server or IIS setup, I'm sure of it. I use text/json all the time. Another website on the same IIS server works fine with the same code.

Comment: Well it's not correct and causes the browser to serve the page up for download on my machine running IIS7 on Win7. application/json or text/javascript would be correct [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

Comment: I already tried that. The same error occurs. Besides, if I omit it completely, it should still serve data, which is doesn't.

Comment: Sure, I was just responding about the mime type causing the download dialog. What headers are you getting from your ajax request? If you remove the `cfcontent` tag and hit the cfc from the address bar with the same URI does it serve the json data?

Comment: If I run the call to the cfc directly from the address bar, i.e. http://www.quirkup.com/cfcs/poll.cfc?method=getPolls&returnformat=json&queryformat=column&uniqueid=1316332117815&poll_id=&count_votes=true&count_comments=true&paging_offset=0&use_offset=true&keyword=, nothing happens. Header information can be viewed in the NET tab of Firefox via the above URL. Or the test page again is http://www.quirkup.com/test.cfm

Comment: Looks like you are getting a CF error that is not being output. I forced an error and still nothing. Switch debug output on in administrator and run the page again.

Comment: @user460114 you say you don't see anything when you open the cfc method url in your browser, but I bet there's something there. After you pull it up in your browser and see nothing, do a view-source. I would expect to see your data encoded as WDDX, which is the default for web services in CF unless you specify otherwise. To specify something else, add `returnformat=json` to the url.